# Problems with my wordpress template made with bootstrap

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been developing a site for the prelaunching campaign of our product on kickstarter.
I had coded the site in bootstrap and then ported it to wordpress.

The thing is that I installed the wordpress prelaunchr plugin. When I try to add the shortcode [prelaunchr] and update the page, appears nothing new on it.

Any kind of hint will be much appreciated.

I have checked the plugin with other wordpress themes and there is no problem so the root of the problem is the bootstrap ported template.

(here is the site, the only thing left is the input for the email which is the thing that prelaunchr generates)

www.pysmile.com

Comment: Was there supposed to be a link to the template?

Comment: here is the theme folder and the link to the website is above-mentioned

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8bxwFZSDBvQfkx5SVpMOE1IZS1uT0ItNVZZZFJISXU1aUZmNlRaVzZOMjFqVUxfTHBDNFE